# Installing sql server 2016, a dll could not be run error code 1723

Tags: sql, dll, windows-10

I'm trying to install sql server 2016 standard version on windows 10 enterprise and it keeps giving me this error on installation.

> There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this installation to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.

The summary file contains the information below:

```
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Failed: see details below
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2068052293
  Start time:                    2016-10-14 11:45:41
  End time:                      2016-10-14 11:47:08
  Requested action:              Install

Setup completed with required actions for features.
Troubleshooting information for those features:
  Next step for SQLEngine:       Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Next step for SNAC:            Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Next step for SNAC_SDK:        Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.


Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  DESKTOP-ARR1KHB
  Machine processor count:       8
  OS version:                    Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise (10.0.14393)
  OS service pack:               
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured
  SQL Server 2016      MSSQLSERVER          MSRS13.MSSQLSERVER             Reporting Services - Native              1033                 Standard Edition     13.0.1601.5     No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2016                                                          Data Quality Client                      1033                 Standard Edition     13.0.1601.5     No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2016                                                          LocalDB                                  1033                 Express Edition      13.0.1100.286   No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2016                                                          Reporting Services - SharePoint                                                    13.0.1601.5     No         Yes       

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2016 
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2016
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       13
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation location:         E:\Documents\Programs\Microsoft.SQL.Server.2016.Standard.x64\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          Standard

Product Update Status:
  None discovered.

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        Install
  ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      false
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Manual
  ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
  ASDATADIR:                     Data
  ASLOGDIR:                      Log
  ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
  ASSERVERMODE:                  MULTIDIMENSIONAL
  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            <empty>
  ASTELSVCACCT:                  <empty>
  ASTELSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  ASTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
  BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Automatic
  CLTCTLRNAME:                   <empty>
  CLTRESULTDIR:                  <empty>
  CLTSTARTUPTYPE:                0
  CLTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  CLTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  CLTWORKINGDIR:                 <empty>
  COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0
  COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
  COMMFABRICPORT:                0
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20161014_114540\ConfigurationFile.ini
  CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:               0
  CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                <empty>
  CTLRSVCPASSWORD:               <empty>
  CTLRUSERS:                     <empty>
  ENABLERANU:                    false
  ENU:                           true
  EXTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  EXTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE
  FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
  FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <empty>
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  HELP:                          false
  IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS:      false
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
  INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             <empty>
  INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server
  INSTANCEID:                    MSSQLSERVER
  INSTANCENAME:                  MSSQLSERVER
  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ISTELSVCACCT:                  <empty>
  ISTELSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  ISTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0
  MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:            <empty>
  MATRIXNAME:                    <empty>
  MRCACHEDIRECTORY:              
  NPENABLED:                     0
  PBDMSSVCACCOUNT:               <empty>
  PBDMSSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  PBDMSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  PBENGSVCACCOUNT:               <empty>
  PBENGSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  PBENGSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  PBPORTRANGE:                   <empty>
  PBSCALEOUT:                    false
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         false
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
  ROLE:                          <empty>
  RSINSTALLMODE:                 DefaultNativeMode
  RSSHPINSTALLMODE:              DefaultSharePointMode
  RSSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  RSSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  SAPWD:                         <empty>
  SECURITYMODE:                  <empty>
  SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLCOLLATION:                  Persian_100_CI_AI
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\MSSQLSERVER
  SQLSVCINSTANTFILEINIT:         false
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           DESKTOP-ARR1KHB\masoud-pc
  SQLTELSVCACCT:                 NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY
  SQLTELSVCPASSWORD:             <empty>
  SQLTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:          Automatic
  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBFILECOUNT:            8
  SQLTEMPDBFILEGROWTH:           64
  SQLTEMPDBFILESIZE:             8
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBLOGFILEGROWTH:        64
  SQLTEMPDBLOGFILESIZE:          8
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE: false
  TCPENABLED:                    1
  UIMODE:                        Normal
  UpdateEnabled:                 true
  UpdateSource:                  MU
  USEMICROSOFTUPDATE:            false
  X86:                           false

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20161014_114540\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Native Client Access Component
  Component error code:          1723
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20161014_114540\sqlncli_Cpu64_1.log
  Error description:             There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this installation to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=13.0.1601.5&EvtType=sqlncli.msi%40RollbackCleanup%401723

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Native Client Access Component
  Component error code:          1723
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20161014_114540\sqlncli_Cpu64_1.log
  Error description:             There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this installation to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=13.0.1601.5&EvtType=sqlncli.msi%40RollbackCleanup%401723

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity SDK
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Native Client Access Component
  Component error code:          1723
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20161014_114540\sqlncli_Cpu64_1.log
  Error description:             There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this installation to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=13.0.1601.5&EvtType=sqlncli.msi%40RollbackCleanup%401723

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

Scenario specific rules:

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20161014_114540\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

here is the link to log file:
[sqlncli_Cpu64_1.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw_1xnMHJ4qkZGxTT2U1RnhMMVk/view?usp=sharing)
can anyone help?

Comment: contact microsoft for support.

Answer (score 2):

I faced same issue on my windows 10 machine, After checking error log in event viewer I found following detail for error

"Product: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client  -- Error 1723. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this installation to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Action **SNAC_SetClientSSNLDefaults_32**, entry: SNAC_SetClientSSNLDefaults, library: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\MSI4206.tmp"

On googling further i found that the entry for 32-bit sql native client dll in sqlncli.msi file is not pointing to the actual dll for sql server native client 2012 dll in system32 folder. You can view or edit this entry using [ORCA MSI Editor](https://www.technipages.com/download-orca-msi-editor). On opening the sqlncli.msi file using ORCA editor and searching for **SNAC_SetClientSSNLDefaults_32** key you can see that the value could be **$DP_sqlncli10_dll_32 = 3** or **$DP_sqlncli_dll_32 = 3** or any previous version of native client but for sql server native client 2012 it should be **$DP_sqlncli11_dll_32 = 3**. I changed and saved this value on every sqlncli.msi file found on my system using ORCA editor. You can search in C:\ProgramData.. folder and setup installation folder for sqlncli.msi file or better if you can use any search tool like **everything**. Thereafter I was able to successfully install SQL Server native client 2012 without any error.

For more details you can refer this link
[Installing Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client](https://shubell.wordpress.com/2018/01/05/installing-microsoft-sql-server-2012-native-client/)

Comment: Thanks i've used this trick with release 17.9.1 of Microsoft SQL Server Management studio,
I have got the sqlncli.msi file from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50402
then after applying your trick I have installed the file then i installed SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe file

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this error a couple of days, when trying to install SQL Server 2016. Finally got it working by removing MS Visual C++ 2010 Runtime from Programs and Features. SQL Server installs this in setup process again. So, my advise is to remove C++ 2010 Runtime. This solution fixes same installation that occurs with SSMS.
So, check if there is MS Visual C++ 2010 Runtime installed and uninstall it.

Answer (score 0):

As one can't uninstall sql server completely, and there always will be some components remained, I just reinstalled my windows and this time I installed sql first (before vs2015) and the problem solved. I think there are some issues installing this kind of software and has problem with some dlls.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue trying to update from 2008 -> 2017. I had to update to 2012 SP4 first and then to 2017.